# How is it possible that the Seer from Vikings is still alive?

Tags: character, vikings

The seer was already very old when the series began, but now all the characters are much older and he still looks the same.

How is that possible? Is he some supernatural being? Or is it someone else just looking very similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outward marks of aging may have come earlier in the past due to poor understanding nutrition among other factors, so possibly the seers is younger than appearances suggest. Thus it's possible that not only the seer but the main characters are younger than we expect.

There is also a theory that it's fairly easy to live into 80 in the modern era, but if you got anywhere near that age in the past, you probably had exceptionally good genes.  (i.e. there no modern medicine to give you that bypass operation, etc., to extend your life.  )

[Check out this graph on historical life expectancy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_expectancy#Variation_over_time)

The presumption is that if the seer could make it to old age in the first place, making it to extreme old age is not unlikely.

Comment: I like this answer, but I am not so sure it is correct, after all, it has a lot of guessing.

Comment: @TGar any answer will have to involve speculation short of the writers or producers commenting directly.  As to it being correct, I'm as much in the dark as you, but I'm glad I could at least provide some perspective on the issue.

Comment: I mainly wrote that to comment to explain why it was not accepted already,. But I will accept it eventually if nothing else will be add.